# How to catch all of the files under a path which doesn't have a specific extension and exclude subdirectories?

Tags: regex

I have a folder/file structure as following:

```
/path2files/subfolder1
/path2files/abcd
/path2files/abcd.sh
/path2files/defg
/path2files/defg.sh
/path2files/logs
```

I want to have a regex that matches all files that do not have the .sh extension and exclude the subdirectories.

I cannot figure out an optimized regex to do it.
I got the following, which would match also the subdir:

```
/^((?!\.sh)^.)*$/
```

If anybody could help or at least put me in the right direction?

Note: The "/path2files/" could be "/path/2/files/".
Note2: Anything with a "." after the last "/" is a file.

Comment: It's not possible using only regular expression. There's no way to distinguish a directory from a file, unless you hard-code the names in your expression.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen we need to use some other utiliy to check for file-names and we can't check for a file using regex.,

Comment: The requirement is a regex as the code can't be modified, of course by using perl or bash that would be not too difficult.

Comment: @user2360915 then tell the one who gave you the requirement that regex can't tell by "name" if a file-descriptor represents a file or a directory.

Comment: nope the regex, is in a config file.

Comment: guys, dont need to check the file descriptor. Anything that doesnt have a "." inside is a file.

Comment: So the question now becomes "Regex to capture strings with dots after the final slash but with don't end in '.sh'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches any file with an extension, except `.sh`.

```
.+(?=\.)(?!\.sh)(?!\..+\/)
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3arpk).

For a regex, there is no difference between a directory and a file if there isn't a special notation.

Comment: i have seen `file` as a file name. Files are non decided by the dot extension.

Comment: I know - but without the `.`, how can you differentiate the folder `file` from the file `file`?

Comment: that's why we have to use some other utility like `find`. `find . -type f` for files.

Comment: @user2360915 and i have also seen directories with `.` extension.

Comment: note that this would find a match in `/path2files/logs.gpp/bar`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Nice catch. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex to match all the file-names which have dot extension except the one which ends with `.sh`.

```
^.+\.(?!sh$)[^.\/]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lM1tP9/4)